# How to get a Series's parent DataFrame in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Does a `pandas.Series` instance do know it's parent `pandas.DataFrame` when it comes from there?

Example:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'col': range(10)})

series_column = df.col

print('My parent is {}'.format(series_column.parent))

# or
print('My parent is {}'.format(df.col.parent))
```

My goal is to make the signature of a method easier.

```
def foobar(data: DataFrame, column: str):
    return data[column].do_something()

# I would like to save one argument
def foobar(column: pandas.Series):
    return column.parent[column].do_something()
```

Here is a more real world example:

```
def frequency(data: pandas.DataFrame, column: str, dropna: bool = False):
    tab = data[column].value_counts(dropna=dropna)

    # sort index if it is an ordered category
    if data[column].dtype.name == 'category':
        if data[column].cat.ordered:
            tab = tab.sort_index()

    # Series to DataFrame
    tab = tab.to_frame()

    # two column MultiIndex
    a = random_label()
    tab[a] = column
    tab = tab.reset_index()
    tab = tab.set_index([a, column])
    tab.index.names = (None, None)

    tab.columns = ['n']

    return tab
```

Comment: I would say no, at least not in a documented way...

Comment: possibly fragile but `s._cacher[1]()`. if this is not out of curiosity, then if you tell the problem it is supposed to address, perhaps there are better ways.

Comment: Mhm... `_cacher` seems to work in the first place but after comparing `df == df.col._cacher[1]()` I see differences.

Comment: There is `series_column._get_cacher()`, but it's undocumented, this is what is used internally to determine the possibility to assign without `SettingwithCopyWarning`, you can combine it with `series_column._is_view`

Comment: in the edited part, why are you going to the parent frame only to come back at the series again? i.e., why not  column.do_something() in the first place?

Comment: Because the column need to keep part of the dataframe. I don't want to do `df.col = foobar(df.col)`

Comment: @buhtz can you provide an example of `do_something`?

Comment: you're returning so don't do the assignment anyway i'd say. anyway, `_`-starting attributes above shouldn't be depended on as they are not for public use and fragile to change anytime completely. not worth for decreasing one parameter IMHO.